# Jquery doesnt work after page redirection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php page named layers.php which has a table. I have a given a link for each of the table rows to go to page named viewlayers.php Following is the code for my table for redirection

```
    while (  $layer = $records->fetch() )
 {  
    echo "<td><a href=viewlayers.php?layer_id=".$layer['layer_id']." target='_blank'>".$layer['layer_id']."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$layer['tempSP']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$layer['tempPV']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$layer['layer_time']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$layer['EPC360']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$layer['TMAtemp']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

In viewlayers.php , i have added a button named test with a simple jquery script as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#testbtn").click( function() {
    alert("Jquery working!!");

    });

});// end of document ready
```

Is there any bug or am I doing something wrong while redirection ??
Am new to using jquery and javascript. Please explain with an example.

Comment: Do your button have `id` with value `testbtn`?

Comment: Check if there are errors on console.  Press F12

Comment: you need to show us the html for viewlayers. secondly, check for errors in the console.

Comment: Your HREF value in the table doesn't have any surrounding quotes. I would change your php surrounding quotes to `'` and use `"` around the href like this:

`echo '<td><a href="viewlayers.php?layer_id='.$layer['layer_id'].'" target="_blank">'.$layer['layer_id'].'</a></td>';`

Although this isn't an issue, it's still nice to use like this

Comment: Also you're redirecting to vewlayers.php but not to view_layers.php

Comment: @ReneKorss -- Yes I have button with id testbtn.

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND -- Where do I need to press F12. I am writing my code in Eclipse

Comment: @KanchoIliev -- Sorry for confusion. It was my typo mistake. Its viewlayers.php only. I have edited the part.

Comment: @sravankumar , Check it on your browser buddy (install firebug)

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND -- I have installed fire bug and I am checking in script tab my jquery script. I have got the problem. The problem is the code which I write in the eclipse in my jquery script is not getting updated in the server. That is, If I do any modifications in my script, it is not showing the same in firebug ( it is showing an older script ). Is it the problem with my eclipse or server or my mozilla browser which I am using. However the script runs fine when I rename the script and reload the page. Any suggestions regarding this

Comment: Clear cache CTRL +F5    press 2-3 times

Comment: check error, they are highlighted in red color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81407/discussion-between-sravan-kumar-and-mangesh-sathe-ind).

Comment: why is this question upvoted?

Answer (score -1):

Actually there was no problem with jquery. It works at the time of redirection also. The problem was due to the fact that script was not getting updated at the server side. There was some problem with browser cache ( using mozilla browser ). It works perfectly when browser cache is cleared ( CTRL + F5 ). Also used firebug to know if the script is getting updated in the server.